# jquery/javascript replace image filename in path

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to replace a filename in a path. I found a few solutions for this but I couldnt get any of them to work with my particular situation.

I have 3 elements to work with here....

the trigger image: `http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_thumb_small/public/THUMB-1.jpg`

the replaced image: `http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_preview/public/PREVIEW-IMAGE.jpg`

the replaced href: `http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_full/public/FULL-IMAGE.jpg`

So what I need to do is when I mouse over the trigger image it replaces the replaced image and replaced href image file names but keeps the path as it was.

so when I mouse over the trigger image eg:

```
<div class="product-img-thumb-small">
  <a title="" href="">
    <img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_thumb_small/public/THUMB-4.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

this:

```
  <a class="cloud-zoom" href="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_full/public/FULL-IMAGE.jpg">
    <img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_preview/public/PREVIEW-IMAGE.jpg">
  </a>
```

becomes this:

```
  <a class="cloud-zoom" href="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_full/public/THUMB-4.jpg">
    <img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_preview/public/THUMB-4.jpg">
  </a>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="product-preview-wrapper">
  <div class="product-img-thumb">
    <div id="wrap">
    <a class="cloud-zoom" href="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_full/public/FULL-IMAGE.jpg">
    <img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_preview/public/PREVIEW-IMAGE.jpg">
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-image-wrapper">
  <div class="item-list">
    <ul>
      <li class="first">
        <div class="product-img-thumb-small"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_thumb_small/public/THUMB-1.jpg" /></a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="product-img-thumb-small"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_thumb_small/public/THUMB-2.jpg" /></a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="product-img-thumb-small"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_thumb_small/public/THUMB-3.jpg" /></a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="product-img-thumb-small"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_thumb_small/public/THUMB-4.jpg" /></a></div>
      </li>
      <li class="last">
        <div class="product-img-thumb-small"><a title="" href=""><img src="http://domainname.com/path/to/files/product_thumb_small/public/THUMB-5.jpg" /></a></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I'm using jQuery. I have this so far:

```
$('.product-image-wrapper .product-img-thumb-small img').hover(function () {

   var newImg = $(this).attr("src");
   $(".product-preview-wrapper a.cloud-zoom").attr("href",newImg); 
   $(".product-preview-wrapper a.cloud-zoom img").attr("src",newImg);

});
```

But the issue is with the path.. I dont want ot replace the path.. just the image filename.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Regards
C

Comment: I think you should add the jquery you have right now and remove all the unnecessary code...just add what is necessary to clearify your question.

Comment: I dont really have any jquery.. I have as far as this: `$('.product-image-wrapper .product-img-thumb-small img').hover(function () {})`

Comment: I tried loads of things eg: `preview.attr('src').substring(0,preview.attr('src').lastIndexOf('/')+1 )` but I dont see the point of pasting the things i tried that DONT work.

Comment: updated with what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out:

```
$('.product-image-wrapper .product-img-thumb-small img').mouseover(function () {

        var preview = $('.product-preview-wrapper .product-img-thumb img');
        var previewPath = preview.attr('src').substring(0,preview.attr('src').lastIndexOf('/') +1 );
        var zoom = $('.product-preview-wrapper .product-img-thumb a.cloud-zoom');
        var zoomPath = zoom.attr('href').substring(0,zoom.attr('href').lastIndexOf('/') +1 );
        var imageName = $(this).attr('src').substring($(this).attr('src').lastIndexOf('/') +1);

       $(".product-preview-wrapper a.cloud-zoom").attr("href", zoomPath + imageName); 
       $(".product-preview-wrapper a.cloud-zoom img").attr("src", previewPath + imageName);

    });
```

Please let me know if there is a better way though.

Answer (score 2):

To replace the `href` in your `cloud-zoom` element. Try this:

```
$(".product-img-thumb-small img").mouseover(function(){
   var imgUrl = $(this).attr("src");
   $(".cloud-zoom").attr("href",imgUrl); 
   $(".cloud-zoom img").attr("src",imgUrl);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dotbart/EMm8Z/)

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I waht the filenames (without path) for the image in `<div class="product-img-thumb-small">` to replace the filname (leaving the path as it is) the the href in `<a class="cloud-zoom" href="">` and also replace the image src in that same `<a>` tag while also keep the original path as they where.. just replaceing the image filename.

I hope that makes more sence.

Comment: the replacement take place with the image in <div class="product-img-thumb-small"> has mouse over/hover

Comment: Oh I see, check if the updated solution matches your question

Comment: Thank but I still have the issue of the path need to stay the same as it was ... only the filename is replaced.

Comment: is it better to use `mouseover()` rather than `hover()`